# How to disable input in TextBox after it reaches its max length

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have set my textbox maxlength to 20, where I am using validation control to give the error message and it works fine, but actually I want it to display character count the moment user starts entering input in textbox and when it reaches 20 character then user should not be able to type in it.
Can this be done, Can anyone shed light on it please:

Comment: can you use jQuery? If yes I can write a example for you?

Comment: @MajidParvin Yes please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write this code as simple as possible. You need handle some other event such as **onPaste** as well and write it more efficient. By the way.

I assumed:
 You have jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

And these Control:

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="lblCount" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

You need just some JavaScript code like this:

```
<script>
            var max = 20;
            var lblCount = $("[id$='lblCount']");
            var txtMessage = $("[id$='txtMessage']");

            function checkCount(padding) {
                var currentLength = txtMessage.val().length;
                if (currentLength >= 20) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    lblCount.text(max - currentLength - padding);
                }
                return true;
            }


            lblCount.text(max);
            txtMessage.keypress(function (e) {
                var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (key != 8 && key != 46) {
                    if (!checkCount(1)) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    };
                };
            });
            txtMessage.keyup(function (e) {
                var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (key != 8 && key != 46) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }
                checkCount(0);
            });
        </script>
```

In very start part of JavaScript code I defined max, lblCount an txtMessage that you must be aware of them.

Comment: I've changed it to simpler.

Comment: It worked, thanks for sharing it. I have one query just for my information can this not be done without using <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script> why do we need to use it?

Comment: @Dharam Rai It possible to write all of this codes without jQuery but jQuery makes a lots of features and browser compatibility that might be useful. If you have no idea about **jQuery** I suggest you it to learn.

Comment: Thanks for all these, ya I need to learn more of jQuery. One more if I'll use jQuery in my site will this bring a chance of popping up unnecessary advertisement in my page? Sorry if it sound stupid but need to know if so :)

Comment: one more query, when the input reaches maxlength then backspace or delete doesn't work? can you fix this for me, I want backspace and delete to work here even after the maxlength reaches.

Comment: what's your browser?

Comment: i tested it with latest version of Chrome and Firefox and it works.

Comment: yup it works for chrome but doesn't work for firefox. Anyways all thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Javascript for this :

**JS**

```
function tocheck(field, count, limit)
{
if (field.value.length > limit)
   field.value = field.value.substring(0, limit);
else
   count.value = limit - field.value.length;
}
```

**Asp.net**

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" TextMode="MultiLine"  Width="200px" Rows="3" 
runat="server"  onkeyup="tocheck(txtMessage, this.form.remLen, 20);" onkeydown="tocheck(txtMessage, this.form.remLen, 20);" />
```

In another textbox you check the count:

```
<input readonly="readonly" type="text" name="remLen" size="3" maxlength="3" value="160" />
```

Comment: @Tadej OP wants to show the Count and for these type of Validation should be done on ClientSide rather than Server Side

Comment: I want to give a try to your code but I want to know why is width="200" because I am using class to control it, do I need to set width="200"? if I don't won't this code work?

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="200px" Rows="3" runat="server"
                            onkeyup="tocheck(txtMessage, this.form.remLen, 20);" onkeydown="tocheck(txtMessage, this.form.remLen, 20);" />
                        <br />
                        <input readonly="readonly" type="text" name="remLen" size="3" maxlength="3" value="160" />

Comment: it wasn't showing an error but wasn't working maybe I made a mistake somewhere. But I got answered, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If TextBox1.Text.Length >= 25 Then 
        If e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

'25 is the Limit User Input